# how to hide menu slider on clicking a body using react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to hide menu slider onclicking a body in **reactjs**. how can i do that in function using **react.js**.

```
document.querySelector('.open-menu').onclick = function(){
  html.classList.add('active');
};

document.querySelector('.close-menu').onclick = function(){
  html.classList.remove('active'); 
};

html.onclick = function(event){
  if (event.target === html){
    html.classList.remove('active');
  }
};
```

I want this same functionality in react js.

Comment: Hey! Although there are some answers already, it would be great, if you could provide some context for your challenge. Is it an application that already uses React, what is a menu itself? I think this will help you to get a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [isMenuOpen, showMenu] = useState(false)

  const toggleMenu = () => showMenu(!isMenuOpen)

    return (
      <>
        {isMenuOpen && <MenuCompoment />}
        <div onClick={toggleMenu}><App /></div>
      </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a stripped down version of code I've used before.
UseEffect on mounting of the Menu adds an event listener on the document for the click event.

When a click happens it uses closest to look up the parent tree of elements for an id (note the '#')
If it finds one, then the click happened on the menu otherwise it happened on any other element so close.

When the menu is disposed the return function of useEffect is called and removes the event handler.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const Page = () => {

    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

    return <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={e => setToggle(!toggle)}>Toggle</button>
        { toggle && <Menu show={toggle} hide={() => setToggle(false)}/>}
    </div>
}

const Menu = ({show, hide}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("click", listen);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("click", listen);
        }
    }, []);

    const listen = e => {
        if (!e.target.closest("#menu")) {
           hide();
        }
    }

    return <div className="menu" id="menu">
            <span>I'm a menu</span>
        </div>;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think setting onclick event on the menuItems like this will Work
`onClick={()=> setOpen(!open)}`

```
export function SidebarMenu({open, setOpen}) {

return (
        <div open={open}> 

      <Link to="#" title="Home"  onClick={()=> setOpen(!open)} >Home</Link>
       </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late for answer but since I saw it in active feed, I will try my best to answer it.

I can see that if your menu is open, you want to hide it if clicked anywhere else. I have used useRef to store the menu node and I compare it to the document whenever its open, if it is, I close the menu

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-cookies-rq5m9?file=/src/App.js)